# Tkinter Passing Functions one to other

Tags: python, tkinter

Python: 3.8.0

I Want to make one python file for functions and other for the main code

EXAMPLE

file1.py [MY MAIN FILE]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import file2

win = tk.Tk()

labeltest = Label(win, text="Hello World")

win.mainloop()
```

file2.py [the one I want the functions in]

```
import file1

def testfunc():
labeltest.pack()
```

and I don't know why it is giving me a error please help

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are trying to do is known as circular import which is not allowed in python.to solve this its either you: 
1: merge the two files(but you need two program files )
2: which i think is your solution , you call the import when need in the particular statement.

file1.py becomes

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

win = tk.Tk()

labeltest = Label(win, text="Hello World")

win.mainloop()
```

file2 becomes:

```
def testfunc():
    import file1
    file1.labeltest.pack()
```

Hit me up if you encounter more probs